# How to store a http request response in a local variable and use it within any of my files?

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

My http requests response returns an Object and I don't know how to assign it to a local variable and use it around between different files. How would i do that?

```
    axios.post(url + '/qget?sub=' + sub)
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I just want to take the response `data` and assign that to a variable I could export and use in my other files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Comment: Check the above link for some tips. It also has a link to another related question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice those didn't help I even tried declaring the variable as global and it refused to read it in the then and just redeclared that there

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You could export a function which accepts data as a parameter from another module. Then you can call that exported function within the `then` callback so that the other module now has access to the http data.

some module:

```
export function doSomethingWithData(data) {
    // logic...
}
```

original file:

```
// ...

import { doSomethingWithData } from './someModule'

// ...

axios.post(url + '/qget?sub=' + sub)
.then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    doSomethingWithData(data)
})
.catch(err => console.log(err)); 

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `localStorage` that is part of Web Storage API:

```
axios.post(url + '/qget?sub=' + sub)
    .then(data => localStorage.setItem('storedData',data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And then each time you retrieve it with `localStorage.getItem`:

```
let retrievedData = localStorage.getItem('storedData');
```

Note: never treat `localStorage` as secure, thus don't store any confidential data

About localStorage:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage